# How to JOIN tables in Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, resultset, spring-jdbc, rowmapper

I am creating a custom query in Spring using JDBC to join the tables that are in my Database, but when I check the endpoint in PostMan only the results one table appear. Any insight would be helpful.

This is the query:

```
 @Override
    public List <User> getAllUserData(int id){
        String sql = """
                SELECT * 
                FROM user u
                INNER JOIN vehicle v
                   ON u.id = v.userId
                INNER JOIN home h
                    on u.id = h.userId
                WHERE id = ?
                """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserRowMapper(), id );
```

The Row Mapper:

```
 @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
        return new User(
                rs.getInt("id"),
                rs.getNString("first_name"),
                rs.getNString("last_name"),
                rs.getNString("email")
                );
    }
```

The endpoint result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Johnnie",
    "lastName": "Hicks",
    "email": "johnnie@test.com"
}
```

What I am expecting:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "first",
    "lastName": "last",
    "email": "firstLast@test.com",
    vehicle: [{
    "make": "nissan",
    "model": "pathfinder"
    }]
    home: [{
    "type": "apartment" 
    }]
}
```

Comment: Your mapper doesn't map the `vehicle` or `home` columns.

Comment: in row mapper you just map id,first_name , last_name , email not other objects